# send email without outlook help (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
START mailto:bharanikumariyer@gmail.com?subject=Errorˆ&body=Returncode%%20%errorlevel%%%20was%%20returned%%20by%%20the%%20backup%%20program.
```

I'm trying to send email with the code above, but it starts up Outlook. How can I send email without Outlook using just batch code? The destination address can be hardcoded in the script.

Comment: possible duplicate superuser.com/questions/63081/windows-command-line-emailer

Comment: my question is , with batch program, send email without outlook program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a command line email program to use in the batch file - you have to have some application that can do the mail send for you within that context, outlook needs to be actually running to send.

These exist - they've been around for a long *long* time for use in the same sort of context as you've got - but its not something I've ever needed. You may have more success in serverfault.com (by asking for a command line email utility to use to send mail from a batch file).